# Windows UIAutomation is not detecting window element

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I am trying to access the folder using UIAutomation but window element is not detecting.

When i checked with UI Spy it shows the element with class name and process ID. The element i am looking is window element and it comes under explorer process. So when i tried with below code it returns 0 elements. I have attached image for reference. Please help me.

[image]

```
Process[] windowFolders = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
        foreach (Process proc in windowFolders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(proc.GetType());
            proc.Refresh();
            Console.WriteLine(proc.MainWindowHandle);
            if (proc.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32() != 0)
            {
                AutomationElement windowExplorer = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                AutomationElementCollection ewindows = windowExplorer.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.window));
                foreach (AutomationElement ewindow in ewindows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Window Name: " + ewindow.Current.Name + " Window class name: " + ewindow.Current.ClassName);
                }
             }
       }
```

Comment: Why are you fiddling with processes, main windows, etc when automation exposes a [`RootElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.rootelement?view=netcore-3.1) property: "Gets the root AutomationElement for the current desktop."?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you so much. Used root element property and it helped me find the window element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggested i used root element property. With the help of RootElement property found the solution. It is very useful to find elements on current desktop.

Below is the solution which i found my self.

```
AutomationElementCollection desktopChildren = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Windows));
        foreach(AutomationElement dChil in desktopChildren)
        {
            if (dChil.Current.Name.Contains("Chipset Software"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}: Found Chipset_Software Window");
            }
       }
```

Thank you so much @Damien_The_Unbeliever.